# Why is GroupBy multiple fields not grouping correctly>

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, grouping, linq-to-objects

I've got a model object with a Timestamp property, and I want to group these by year and month, so I did this:

```
'group the events by months
Dim months = Model.Events.GroupBy(Function(x) New With {x.Timestamp.Year, x.Timestamp.Month})
```

But this is actually returning a group for every event, even ones with the same year and month:
[image: Incorrect Grouping]

What's going on here? Why is `GroupBy` making a separate group for every event, instead of grouping by year and month, and how can I fix this?

Comment: What are you doing with `months`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only immutable `Key` properties determine equality. If there are no key properties, you get reference equality.

```
New With {Key x.Timestamp.Year, Key x.Timestamp.Month}
```

> **Key Properties**
>
> Key properties differ from non-key properties in several fundamental ways:
>
> - Only the values of key properties are compared in order to determine whether two instances are equal.
> - The values of key properties are read-only and cannot be changed.
> - Only key property values are included in the compiler-generated hash code algorithm for an anonymous type.
>
> **Equality**
>
> Instances of anonymous types can be equal only if they are instances of the same anonymous type. The compiler treats two instances as instances of the same type if they meet the following conditions:
>
> - They are declared in the same assembly.
> - Their properties have the same names, the same inferred types, and are declared in the same order. Name comparisons are not case-sensitive.
> - The same properties in each are marked as key properties.
> - **At least one property in each declaration is a key property.**
>
> **An instance of an anonymous types that has no key properties is equal only to itself.**
>
> *from [Anonymous Types (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx)*

Comment: This was **exactly** the problem and your answer fixed my problem immediately. **Thank You!** I'm kind of amazed that I've been working with LINQ for 10 years and never run into this situation before.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank And I'm using C# for 20 years :-) .NET 3.5 is from 2007 :-) :-) (it remembers me those work ads that ask for 10 years experience with a technology that was created the year before)

Comment: @JoshuaFrank In C# that problem doesn't exist since its anonymous types are immutable and include all fields in equality checks.

Comment: Thanks for the "Key"-hint :-). Altough  I read the article referenced, somehow I've missed this part :-)